# WP_Query create html structure

Tags: wp-query, html

I have a page here to illustrate my question

http://www.ttmt.org.uk.

The first grid is hard coded using the html structure I want - div's to contain each row and then div's inside that to contain each block.

My problem is how do I create this structure in a WP_Query.

If I output the row in the WP_Query it will give me 1 block in each row. I want three blocks in each row.

Do I need some sort of loop within a loop?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 6</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 7</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 8</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 9</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="container two">

        <h3>With WP_Query</h3>

        <?php
            $grid_args  = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order'
            );

            $grid_loop = new WP_Query($grid_args);

            if($grid_loop->have_posts()):
                while($grid_loop->have_posts()):
                    $grid_loop->the_post();

        ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
            endif;
        ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in `current_post` and `post_count` vars with php's [modulus operator](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to check where you are in the loop and output markup at the appropriate time.

```
if( $grid_loop->have_posts() ):

    echo '<div class="row">';

    while( $grid_loop->have_posts() ):
        $grid_loop->the_post();

        ?>
        <div class="col-xs-3 box">
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php

        // if this is the third post
        // and not the last post
        // close previous row and open a new one.
        // note: current_post starts at zero, so we add 1 to it
        if( ((($grid_loop->current_post + 1) % 3) == 0)
            && ($grid_loop->current_post + 1) != $grid_loop->post_count  ):
                echo '</div><div class="row">';
        endif;

    endwhile;

    echo '</div>';

endif;
```